# Lenovo A740 BIOS Administrator Password

Tags: bios, passwords, desktop-computer

Quite in a pickle here after a person who left the workplace set the Administrator password on all six of our lab machines. As funny as that might sound it is not. I have tried some common solution found using Google, i.e.:

- CmosPwd
- Remove CMOS battery and hold power button for 20 seconds
- CMOS De-Animator
- Entering the wrong password three times do NOT generate a checksum

None of these things have worked and Lenovo is acting really weird here in India stating that this is not supported and will not help. I simply can not be the first person with this problem on machines that are under warranty. I know replacing the motherboard would work, obviously, but since they are not helping I am at a loss right now!

Any ideas around this would be Welcome!

Respectfully
Petter

Answer (score 1):

If the BIOS administrator password has been set is cannot be removed without changing the motherboard or returning it to Lenovo. This is by design to protect the computer from unauthorised access. Your reasoning might be entirely legitimate but the password cannot be removed.

We use Lenovo equipment and have had the same (in the UK). The device has a new motherboard as that's the only solution.

If the person who has left has changed the password and won't give it to you then you should begin legal proceedings to either get them to remove the password or to compensate you for the replacement/repair of the devices at their own expense.