# BIOS is unusable (Lenovo laptop)

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, lenovo-laptop

Some weeks ago, I set a master (administrator) password for BIOS, so that each time I open my laptop, I am getting prompted to enter it (just some safety measure). Recently, I have observed that I cannot change the BIOS settings anymore (not even remove the password), because I am not an *administrator*, as a BIOS warning says.

Furthermore, because of this problem, I cannot boot from any external media (I wanted to reinstall Linux - boot from EFI USB drive).

I looked in every corner of the BIOS and could not find any relevant setting or even a way to enter BIOS as an administrator. The reset pin on the laptop was not do much help either. I have also tried to remove the CMOS battery, drain all the extra current and put it back after a few minutes, but to no avail.

The last thing I tried was a BIOS update: I launched the update utility from windows, prompted for a restart, I was asked to enter the BIOS password, and after that it booted straight to windows, no update being made.

Thus being said, I would greatly appreciate any idea of what I can try next.
Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Laptop is a Lenovo B50-80.

Comment: [Lenovo A740 BIOS Administrator Password](https://superuser.com/questions/1102277/lenovo-a740-bios-administrator-password)

Comment: [Types of password for ThinkPad](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht036206) by attention to the Supervisor password portion of the page.  Specifically the instructions on how to remove the password you did set.

Comment: @Ramhound - Thanks for the link. I still hope there's a workaround, without sending it to Lenovo.

Comment: Read both links....

Comment: [This](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/128167/How+to+disable+bios+password+on+lenovo+netbook) might be relevant entirely up to you to determine if it is or isn't though.  Have you verified the [supervisor password](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht036206) it is asking for isn't the same password you set?  Entirely depends if you created a user + master password or not.  If none of this information is helpful, then you are out of luck, because there isn't a way to reset the supervisor password (and I assume you don't know it) which means the motherboard must be replaced.

Comment: @Ramhound - Thanks for the help. My Lenovo B50-80 does not have a thing similar to ThinkPad Setup program. I can only access the BIOS by pressing F2, and inside, under the `security` tab, I can only change the password, but not remove it.

Comment: Change the password to be blank. That's how you remove it.

Comment: I've managed to enter BIOS as an administrator, but the problem now is that new settings **can't be saved**. For example, I tried to remove both the administrator and the user password, saved and exit BIOS, but upon restart I was prompted again to enter the password. The battery is perfectly good (checked it with a multimeter). Any ideas?